# Why does my UINavigationController send a message to a Zombie?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, orientation, release, uitableview

I have a weird problem.

I have a UINavigationController with UITableViewController inside.

In a nutshell: UINavigationController + UITableViewController + change device orientation causes:

```
[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

The problem: after fast scrolling table and changing device orientation a few times the "[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance" error appears.

I debug it through "Allocations" and see:

```
0 CALayer Malloc 1 UIKit [UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
1 CALayer Zombie -1 QuartzCore CA::release_objects<X::List<void const*>*)
```

What does it mean and what I supposed to do?

Comment: Having the same problem, did you ever find out what caused it?

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have a memory management issue.

The best bet for you would be to `Analyze your code`, which you can do with `CMD+SHIFT+A`. It will run a static analysis of your code and mark with nice blue arrows the places where the [clang analyser](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html) reports possible memory issues.

As a guess, I'd wager that you have a problem in a viewDidAppear / viewDidDisappear.